# Red and orange lights appear to be blinking

Tags: visible-light, vision, perception

[image]

Why does the red and orange lights appear to be "blinking" and the blue and green lights appear to be still? The lights on this hula hoop are always stagnant, and in every picture this exact same thing happens.

Comment: I don't see any blinking effect in your image, but what you're experiencing might be related to the [flickering wheel illusion](http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/neuroskeptic/2013/08/21/can-you-see-your-own-brain-waves/#.XPdGBzd_WdM) of Sokoliuk and VanRullen.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about physics